# Triangles question and Area

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

Let ∆ABC be any triangle, where points $E, F, C$ are collinear, $D, E, B$ are
collinear, $A, D, F$ are collinear and such that $| CF | = | F E |, | DE | = | EB |, | AD | = | DF |$,
as in the following figure:

If $| AC | = | CB |=\sqrt{14}$ dm and Area (∆DEF) = 0.01 $m^{2}$
, so calculate $| AB |$ in cm.

Hello, can you help me with this Geometry problem? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. We can help you. Show please your attempts before.

Comment: Can't think of how to calculate segment AB? But, we can say that the triangle ABC is isosceles.

Comment: There's a coordinate wolframalpha proof that $|AB|=\sqrt{28}\mathrm{dm}$ [here](https://tio.run/##Jc5NCoMwEAXgfU7hOo1apStDFr1BwWVwMT8JFWpbVApFPHs6sZvhmwczvAnWe5hgHQlS4tC5DQzulqOIDO9WBSHHkoNVjJ1r9SGSMJxaHaIs0LmSBZBTKhmsIvwTJc2Eg0vnmrrVV1w8aC5R02DVHCTuX49P8BtQBeRcczGEFeGhRaYB5867yeVMriVnt3l8rr4fp/djjF8PWAEWdVXIu2FI6Qc). I can show you the vector proof if you show your attempts before. Otherwise the question is going to be closed and deleted thus I would have no point taking time to write down the solution I already know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should notice that:

$$P_{ABD}=2P_{DEF}\tag{1}$$

Why is that so? Obviously $AD=DF$. But the height of triangle $ABD$ drawn from point $B$ perpendicular to the side $AD$ is twice the hight of triangle $DEF$ drawn from point $E$ perpendicular to the side $DF$ (because $DB=2DE$). Strict proof is elementary and I leave it up to you.

In the same way you can show that:

$$P_{AFC}=P_{AEB}=2P_{DEF}\tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2) it follows that the area $P$ of triangle $ABC$ is:

$$P=7P_{DEF}=0.07\text{m}^2=7\text{dm}^2$$

Triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with $AC=b=\sqrt{14}\text{dm}$. Denote with $a$ the length of basis $AB$ and with $h$ the corresponding height drawn from point $C$ perpendicular to segment $AB$.

We have the following equations:

$$\frac{ah}2=P\tag{3}$$

$$\left(\frac a2\right)^2+h^2=AC^2=b^2\tag{4}$$

From (3):

$$h=\frac{2P}a\tag{5}$$

Replace that into (4):

$$\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{4P^2}{a^2}=b^2$$

$$a^4-4b^2a^2+16P^2=0$$

$$a^2=\frac{4b^2\pm\sqrt{16b^4-64P^2}}{2}$$

$$a^2=2b^2\pm2\sqrt{b^4-4P^2}$$

$$a^2=2\cdot14\pm\sqrt{14^2-4\cdot7^2}=28$$

$$a=2\sqrt{7}\text{dm}$$

Comment: Why don't we use $P_{ABC}=\frac{1}{2}|AC|\cdot |CB|\sin \angle ACB =7$ hence $\angle ACB$ is right and then Pythagora's or cosine rule?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Yes, that is possible but I did not pay attention to it. My solution will work even if $\angle ACB$ is not right.

Answer (score 0):

It's better late than never. Vectors approach.
The only benefit of vectors approach I see -- it's fast and requires no thinking. "0. Choose convinient basis. 1. **Express** all what's given and what's needed via basis vectors. 2 **Solve** system of equations. 3. Don't think".
However, the choosing basis step requires some thinking or some experience.

Here we could choose the basis of $\overrightarrow{AB},\,
\overrightarrow{AC}$ but then expressing the area of $\triangle DEF$ would be troblesome. Instead, we choose $e:=\overrightarrow{DE},\,f:=\overrightarrow{DF}$ as basis vectors (and $D$ as the origin, meaning $X=x\mathbf{e}+y\mathbf{f}$ reads $\overrightarrow{DX}=x\mathbf{e}+y\mathbf{f}$).
I think you don't mind if I borrow your image

[image]

$$A=-f,\,C=f+\overrightarrow{EF}=2f-e,\,B=2e$$
We need $|AC|$ and $|CB|$:
$$\overrightarrow{CA}=A-C=-3f+e,\,
\overrightarrow{CB}=B-C=3e-2f$$
We result in a linear transform:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\overrightarrow{CA}\\
\overrightarrow{CB}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-3\\ 3&-2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{e}\\ \mathbf{f}
\end{pmatrix}$$
It's known that a linear transform $x\to Ax$ scales areas by $|A|$ times, thus $$\mathrm{Area}_{ABC}=\operatorname{abs}\left(\left|
\begin{array}{cc}1&-3\\ 3&-2\end{array}\right|\right)\mathrm{Area}_{DEF}=7\mathrm{Area}_{DEF}$$
then we can $$\mathrm{Area}_{ABC}=\frac12\cdot|CA|\cdot|CB|\cdot\sin\angle ACB$$ hence we find $$\sin\angle ACB=1$$ and then apply cosine rule to find $AB$. However, it requires some thinking.

Let's go the straight way:
$$\cos \angle EDF=\frac{e\cdot f}{|e|\cdot|f|},$$
$$\cos^2 \angle EDF=\frac{(e\cdot f)^2}{e^2\cdot f^2},$$
$$\sin^2 \angle EDF=1-\frac{(e\cdot f)^2}{e^2\cdot f^2},$$
but $$\left(\mathrm{Area}_{DEF}\right)^2=
\frac14 e^2 f^2 \sin^2 \angle EDF=
\frac14\left(e^2\cdot f^2-(e\cdot f)^2\right)$$
Hence we have (I'll have decimeter as an unit):
$$\begin{cases}
CA^2=9f^2-6ef+e^2=14\\
CB^2=9e^2-12ef+4f^2=14\\
\frac14\left(e^2\cdot f^2-(e\cdot f)^2\right)=1
\end{cases}$$
solvig this for $e^2,\,f^2,\,ef$ will result in a quadratic equation. However let's feed it to wolframalpha, obtaining
[$$
\begin{cases}
e^2 = \frac{26}{7}\\
f^2 = \frac{20}{7}\\
ef = \frac{18}{7}
\end{cases}
$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9*y-6*z%2Bx%3D14%2C+9*x-12*z%2B4*y%3D14%2C+1%2F4*%28x*y-z%5E2%29%3D1)
and $$AB^2=(B-A)^2=(2e+f)^2=4e^2+4ef+f^2=28.$$